# Dropdown call api from ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Hello i am lost how can i call api from my drop down list

This is a html code

```
 <div class="col">
                                      <label for="text4" class="col-form-label">Price Mode</label> 
                                      <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm col-10" id="select-price-mode">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                      </select>
                                      </div>
```

This is my api using ajax

```
$.ajax({
    // The url that you're going to post 
    /* 
    
    This is the url that you're going to put to call the
    backend api,
    in this case, it's 
    https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8080/api/get (production env)

    */
    url:"https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8080/api/get",
    // The HTTP method that you're planning to use
    // i.e. GET, POST, PUT, DELETE 
    // In this case it's a get method, so we'll use GET
    method:"GET",
    // In this case, we are going to use headers as 
    headers:{
        // The query you're planning to call
        // i.e. <query> can be UserGet(0), RecyclableGet(0), etc.
        query:"<query>",
        // Gets the apikey from the sessionStorage
        apikey:sessionStorage.getItem("apikey")
    },
    success:function(data,textStatus,xhr) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(xhr,textStatus,err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

and this my json response

```
[
    {
        "PriceMode": "Price By Recyclables"
    },
    {
        "PriceMode": "Service Charger"
    }
]
```

My drop down are Price by Recyclables and Service charger

how can i do it ?

Comment: Are you just looking for [a `change` event](https://api.jquery.com/change/) handler?  Or are you trying to *populate* your `<select>` with the values from the AJAX response?  It's not really clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: hi i think it be a select option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking to add your AJAX results as `<option>` elements to your `<select>`.  In your AJAX success handler simply loop over the resulting array and add each element as an `<option>`.  For example:

```
success: function(data) {
    for (let option of data) {
        $('#select-price-mode').append($('<option>', {
            value: option.PriceMode,
            text: option.PriceMode
        }));
    }
}
```

Caveat: If you have *many* options then this could reduce performance.  In cases like that it may be preferable to build one big HTML string of `<options>` and append the whole thing to the `<select>` afterward.  Though in cases where there are *many* options you'd probably want to re-think using a simple `<select>` anyway.